# No funciona correctamente mi web por culpa de los Warnings montado en una pila LAMP en un clúster de Kubernetes

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, kubernetes, lampp

Estoy desplegando una pila LAMP en KInD (Kubernetes), soy estudiante y no tengo mucho conocimiento.
He conseguido montar un clúster de 2 pods, uno con mysql 8.0.33 y otro con php8 + apache2, si utilizo XAMP en local (Ubuntu 20.04) puedo manejar mi tienda web sin ningun problema, puedo hacer consultas a la base de datos, moverme entre páginas gracias al "header: Location ..." de PHP, usar mi barra de búsqueda desarrollada con AJAX y PHP, etc.
Pero a la hora de crear mi pila en el clúster de Kubernetes me salen errores como este al usar mi barra de búsqueda:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in /var/www/html/PHP/buscador.php:20 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/PHP/buscador.php(20): mysqli_num_rows(false) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/PHP/buscador.php on line 20
```

O no me inicia sesión porque ejecuta el header antes que crear el $SESSION['correo'] (en local funciona bien), cosas así, por ejemplo al intentar añadir algo a la cesta debería llevar al usuario al login para iniciar sesión si no lo ha hecho pero me salta este error en el clúster (cosa que en local no me pasa y funciona todo correctamente):

```
Warning: Undefined array key "correo" in /var/www/html/PHP/ProductosHTML/Altavoz/Polk Reserve R600.php on line 4

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/PHP/ProductosHTML/Altavoz/Polk Reserve R600.php:4) in /var/www/html/PHP/ProductosHTML/Altavoz/Polk Reserve R600.php on line 5
```

He copiado literalmente el archivo php.ini de mi XAMP local y lo he metido en el clúster sustituyendo el php.ini-development y el php.ini-production, lo único que consigo es que no me salten los Warnings pero sigue sin funcionar correctamente como en local.

Agradecería un poco de ayuda porque no se como solucionar algo así y he estado buscando bastante en internet y no consigo relacionar este error en ningún lado. Gracias.

Objetivo: Desplegar una tienda web con apache, php, y mysql en un clúster de Kubernetes.

Archivo php.ini que copio de XAMPP y meto en el apache2 del pod de Kubernetes (de esta manera no me aparecen los errores pero sigue sin funcionar correctamente el código, mientras que en local con XAMPP sí que funciona):

```
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Error handling and logging ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; This directive informs PHP of which errors, warnings and notices you would like
; it to take action for. The recommended way of setting values for this
; directive is through the use of the error level constants and bitwise
; operators. The error level constants are below here for convenience as well as
; some common settings and their meanings.
; By default, PHP is set to take action on all errors, notices and warnings EXCEPT
; those related to E_NOTICE and E_STRICT, which together cover best practices and
; recommended coding standards in PHP. For performance reasons, this is the
; recommend error reporting setting. Your production server shouldn't be wasting
; resources complaining about best practices and coding standards. That's what
; development servers and development settings are for.
; Note: The php.ini-development file has this setting as E_ALL. This
; means it pretty much reports everything which is exactly what you want during
; development and early testing.
;
; Error Level Constants:
; E_ALL             - All errors and warnings (includes E_STRICT as of PHP 5.4.0)
; E_ERROR           - fatal run-time errors
; E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR  - almost fatal run-time errors
; E_WARNING         - run-time warnings (non-fatal errors)
; E_PARSE           - compile-time parse errors
; E_NOTICE          - run-time notices (these are warnings which often result
;                     from a bug in your code, but it's possible that it was
;                     intentional (e.g., using an uninitialized variable and
;                     relying on the fact it is automatically initialized to an
;                     empty string)
; E_STRICT          - run-time notices, enable to have PHP suggest changes
;                     to your code which will ensure the best interoperability
;                     and forward compatibility of your code
; E_CORE_ERROR      - fatal errors that occur during PHP's initial startup
; E_CORE_WARNING    - warnings (non-fatal errors) that occur during PHP's
;                     initial startup
; E_COMPILE_ERROR   - fatal compile-time errors
; E_COMPILE_WARNING - compile-time warnings (non-fatal errors)
; E_USER_ERROR      - user-generated error message
; E_USER_WARNING    - user-generated warning message
; E_USER_NOTICE     - user-generated notice message
; E_DEPRECATED      - warn about code that will not work in future versions
;                     of PHP
; E_USER_DEPRECATED - user-generated deprecation warnings
;
; Common Values:
;   E_ALL (Show all errors, warnings and notices including coding standards.)
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE  (Show all errors, except for notices)
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT  (Show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings.)
;   E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR  (Show only errors)
; Default Value: E_ALL
; Development Value: E_ALL
; Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
; http://php.net/error-reporting
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT

; This directive controls whether or not and where PHP will output errors,
; notices and warnings too. Error output is very useful during development, but
; it could be very dangerous in production environments. Depending on the code
; which is triggering the error, sensitive information could potentially leak
; out of your application such as database usernames and passwords or worse.
; For production environments, we recommend logging errors rather than
; sending them to STDOUT.
; Possible Values:
;   Off = Do not display any errors
;   stderr = Display errors to STDERR (affects only CGI/CLI binaries!)
;   On or stdout = Display errors to STDOUT
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/display-errors
display_errors=Off

; The display of errors which occur during PHP's startup sequence are handled
; separately from display_errors. We strongly recommend you set this to 'off'
; for production servers to avoid leaking configuration details.
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/display-startup-errors

; Besides displaying errors, PHP can also log errors to locations such as a
; server-specific log, STDERR, or a location specified by the error_log
; directive found below. While errors should not be displayed on productions
; servers they should still be monitored and logging is a great way to do that.
; Default Value: Off
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: On
; http://php.net/log-errors
log_errors=On

; Set maximum length of log_errors. In error_log information about the source is
; added. The default is 1024 and 0 allows to not apply any maximum length at all.
; http://php.net/log-errors-max-len
log_errors_max_len=1024

; Do not log repeated messages. Repeated errors must occur in same file on same
; line unless ignore_repeated_source is set true.
; http://php.net/ignore-repeated-errors
ignore_repeated_errors=Off

; Ignore source of message when ignoring repeated messages. When this setting
; is On you will not log errors with repeated messages from different files or
; source lines.
; http://php.net/ignore-repeated-source
ignore_repeated_source=Off

; If this parameter is set to Off, then memory leaks will not be shown (on
; stdout or in the log). This is only effective in a debug compile, and if
; error reporting includes E_WARNING in the allowed list
; http://php.net/report-memleaks
report_memleaks=On

; This setting is off by default.
;report_zend_debug = 0

; Turn off normal error reporting and emit XML-RPC error XML
; http://php.net/xmlrpc-errors
;xmlrpc_errors = 0

; An XML-RPC faultCode
;xmlrpc_error_number = 0

; When PHP displays or logs an error, it has the capability of formatting the
; error message as HTML for easier reading. This directive controls whether
; the error message is formatted as HTML or not.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to Off for the CLI SAPI
; http://php.net/html-errors
html_errors=On

; If html_errors is set to On *and* docref_root is not empty, then PHP
; produces clickable error messages that direct to a page describing the error
; or function causing the error in detail.
; You can download a copy of the PHP manual from http://php.net/docs
; and change docref_root to the base URL of your local copy including the
; leading '/'. You must also specify the file extension being used including
; the dot. PHP's default behavior is to leave these settings empty, in which
; case no links to documentation are generated.
; Note: Never use this feature for production boxes.
; http://php.net/docref-root
; Examples
;docref_root = "/phpmanual/"

; http://php.net/docref-ext
;docref_ext = .html

; String to output before an error message. PHP's default behavior is to leave
; this setting blank.
; http://php.net/error-prepend-string
; Example:
;error_prepend_string = "<span style='color: #ff0000'>"

; String to output after an error message. PHP's default behavior is to leave
; this setting blank.
; http://php.net/error-append-string
; Example:
;error_append_string = "</span>"

; Log errors to specified file. PHP's default behavior is to leave this value
; empty.
; http://php.net/error-log
; Example:
;error_log = php_errors.log
error_log="/opt/lampp/logs/php_error_log"
; Log errors to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;error_log = syslog
```

Por ejemplo, al iniciar sesión con un usuario de la base de datos en el login me salta este error (no me pasa solo en esta página pero el error es el mismo):

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/PHP/Cuenta/login.php:4) in /var/www/html/PHP/Cuenta/login.php on line 73
```

A causa de este código:

```
    <body>
    <header>
            <div class="headlogin">
                <a href="../index.php"><img class="logologin" src="../IndexFotos/Logo.jpg"></a>
                <p>TWT_First</p>
            </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <form action="login.php" id="iniciosesion" method="post">
            <div class="forminicio">
                <div class="tablaform1">
                    <h2>INICIO DE SESIÓN</h2>
                    <p class="hrefregistro">¿Es tu primera vez? <u><a href="./registro.php">Registrate</a></u><br><br>
                    Inicia sesión y empieza a disfrutar de todas las ventajas de TWT_First</p>
                    <input type="email" name="correo" class="tdiniciosesion" placeholder="Correo" required><br>
                    <input type="password" name="clave" class="tdiniciosesion" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
                    <div class="divregistro">
                        <input type="submit" class="botoniniciosesion" name="iniciosesion" value="Iniciar Sesión">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </main>
</body>
```

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['iniciosesion'])) {

    # Variables
        $correo = trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['correo']));
        $clave = trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['clave']));

    # Comprobar usuarios
        if (filter_var($correo, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && strlen($clave) >= 8) {

            # Declarar variables
                $_SESSION['correo'] = $correo;
                $clave = md5($clave);
            
            # Conexión con el servidor
                include "../servidor.php";

                $conexion = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);      

            # Consulta
                $query = "select * from usuarios where correo like '$correo' and clave = '$clave'";
                // echo "$query <br>";

            # Ejecutar consulta
                $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,$query) or die ("Fallo en la consulta");
                
            # Nº de filas de la consulta
                $rows = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

            # Dependiendo del tipo de usuario que sea lo manda a su Index correspondiente
                if ($rows == 1) {
                    $bbdd = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);
                    if ($bbdd['tipo_usuario'] == 'admin') {
                        header("Location: ../admin/index.php");
                    }
                    elseif ($bbdd['tipo_usuario'] == 'cliente') {
                        header("Location: ../index.php");
                    }
                }
            # Si el usuario no existe
                else {
                    echo "<p class='alertas'>Este usuario no está dado de alta</p>";
                }
        }
    # Si correo y clave no son correctos
        else {
            echo "<p class='alertas'>El correo o la contraseña no es correcto</p>";
        }

    mysqli_close($conexion);
}
```

?>

He pensado en sustituir los header: Location... por window.location.href="" de javascript, pero no entiendo por qué en un entorno no me da errores y sin embargo en otro sí, y no solo eso sino que además no manda al usuario al index.php.

Por otro lado tengo una barra de búsqueda desarrollada con AJAX y PHP de la cual salta este error desde el body del index.php:

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in /var/www/html/PHP/buscador.php on line 20
```

Y este otro error dentro del div que muestra los resultados generados en buscador.php:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in /var/www/html/PHP/buscador.php on line 27
```

Este es el código relacionado con la barra de búsqueda en index.php:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function buscar_prod(buscar) {
            if (buscar.length > 0) {
                document.getElementById('buscar_1').style = "background-color: white";
                document.getElementById('main').style = "opacity: 0.5";
                document.body.style = "background-color: gray";
                var parametros = {"buscar":buscar};
                $.ajax ({
                    data:parametros,
                    type:'Post',
                    url:'buscador.php',
                    success:function(data) {
                        document.getElementById('datos_buscador').innerHTML = data;
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('buscar_1').style = "background-color: transparent";
                document.getElementById('main').style = "opacity: 1";
                document.body.style = "background-color: lightgray";
                document.getElementById('datos_buscador').innerHTML = '';
            }
        }
    </script>
<div class="buscador">
                        <input onkeyup="buscar_prod($('#buscar_1').val());" type="text" id="buscar_1" name="buscar_1" placeholder="Buscar...">
                    </div>
<div id="datos_buscador"></div>
```

Y a continuación la consulta a la base de datos a través de php en buscador.php:

```
<?php

# Conexión con la bbdd
include("./servidor.php");

$conexion = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname); 

# Consulta
$query = "select nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen from (select nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen from Componentes 
union select nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen from Consolas union select nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen from TVs union select nombre, 
empresa, precio, tabla, imagen from PCs union select nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen from Portátiles union select nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen from Móviles)
 as resultado where nombre like '%".$_POST['buscar']."%' or empresa like '%".$_POST['buscar']."%' or tabla like '%".$_POST['buscar']."%' group by nombre";
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
```

?>

```
<div class="buscadorResult">

<h3>Resultados encontrados: <?php echo $rows ?></h3>

<?php while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) { ?>

    <a href="/PHP/ProductosHTML/<?php echo $resultado['tabla']."/".$resultado['nombre'].".php" ?>"><p><?php echo "<table><tr><td width='10%'><img class='imgbuscador' src='/PHP/Fotos_Productos/".$resultado['tabla'].'/'.$resultado['imagen']."'.jpg ></td><td>".$resultado['nombre']." - ".$resultado['precio']."€</td></tr></table>";?></p></a>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Sería interesante que compartieras el código relacionado con los mensajes de error.

Comment: Todo apunta a que en XAMP la configuración de [`display_errors`](https://php.net/es/errorfunc.configuration#ini.display-errors) evita que aparezcan esos mensajes en el navegador, pero en la configuración del contenedor que has desplegado en kubernetes dicha configuración es diferentes y sí permite mostrar esos datos (que es lo ideal para la fase de desarrollo de la aplicación, pero no para producción). Por favor, comparte también la configuración del `php.ini` relacionada con el tema.

Comment: Gracias por compartir el contenido de `php.ini`, la opción `display_errors=Off` confirma mis sospechas, pero tenemos que mirar el origen del problema y no los síntomas. Tenemos que arreglar el código PHP, que es el que realmente te está dando problemas. ¿Podrías compartir el código que te lanza esas advertencias y errores? Y, si no es molestia, restablece el `php.ini` original y no uses el de XAMP, ya que tiene configuraciones especificas de dicha distribución que podrían afectar el buen funcionamiento del contenedor (como, por ejemplo, `error_log="/opt/lampp/logs/php_error_log"`).

Comment: No se ve `session_start()` por ningún lado...

Comment: Lo tengo declarado al inicio del index y del login además de los demás archivos php que siguen la sesión (en el buscador.php no lo declaro), he omitido bastante código del index que no tiene que ver con mis errores (creo).
De todas formas la variable $_SESSION['correo'] la guarda correctamente, mi problema es que no procesa el header: location... y se estanca en el login.

Comment: He solucionado el problema de los header: location descomentando las líneas "extension=mysqli" y "extension=pdo_mysql" pero con la barra de búsqueda no encuentro el fallo @OscarGarcia

Comment: Ya que has solucionado una parte, deberías actualizar tu pregunta con el estado actual del problema eliminando la parte que has corregido. Ahora mismo hay demasiado ruido en la pregunta que impide poder analizarla de manera rápida. Considera la posibilidad de cerrar esta pregunta y redactar una nueva.

Comment: Tras contactar con el OP sacamos en claro que el problema era una diferencia entre MariaDB 10 que usaba en la pila LAMP (equivalente a MySQL 5.6) y MySQL 8.0 que usaba en kubernetes. Un `group by` inválido que MySQL 5.6 lo permite, en versión 8.0 no lo estaba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mal funcionamiento se debía a una consulta SQL incorrecta que la versión del servidor MySQL (MariaDB 10) era capaz de responder pero que las versiones modernas responden con error:

```
# Consulta
$query = "select nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen from (select nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen from Componentes 
union select nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen from Consolas union select nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen from TVs union select nombre, 
empresa, precio, tabla, imagen from PCs union select nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen from Portátiles union select nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen from Móviles)
 as resultado where nombre like '%".$_POST['buscar']."%' or empresa like '%".$_POST['buscar']."%' or tabla like '%".$_POST['buscar']."%' group by nombre";
```

En una consulta `GROUP BY`no se pueden solicitar campos que no estén agrupados o hagan uso de una función de agrupación (como `SUM`, `COUNT`, `MAX`, etc).

Por lo tanto el `group by nombre` restringía el `select` a solo obtener el campo `nombre`, pero en la consulta se usa `select nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen`.

Bastó con agregar los campos al `GROUP BY` y el problema se quitó:

```
# Consulta
$busqueda = mysql_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['buscar']));
$query = "
    SELECT
      nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen
    FROM (
        SELECT nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen FROM Componentes
        UNION SELECT nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen FROM Consolas
        UNION SELECT nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen FROM TVs
        UNION SELECT nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen FROM PCs
        UNION SELECT nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen FROM Portátiles
        UNION SELECT nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen FROM Móviles
    ) as resultado
    WHERE
      nombre like '%$busqueda%'
      OR empresa like '%$busqueda%'
      OR tabla like '%$busqueda%'
    GROUP BY by nombre, empresa, precio, tabla, imagen
";
```